# Manipulate Report Viewer Webpart Parameters via PowerShell on a SharePoint 2010 WebpartPage?

Tags: web-part, powershell, sharepoint-server, reporting-services, report-viewer

I want to set the parameters of a SSRS report which is displayed through the ReportViewerWebPart by PowerShell, all on SharePoint 2010 WebpartPage.

Right now, I'm confused by the [documentation of the ReportViewerWebpart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.sharepoint.ui.webparts.reportviewerwebpart.aspx).
It states, that you can read in the available Parameters by using the GetParameters-Method (which is working), and use the OverrideParameters-Method to supply custom values.

1. it is not a method, it is a property
2. it is a READ ONLY property

So, how should I set properties for the report where this property is just read only? Is there another possibility to do that instead of using this not working property? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is as simple as that:

```
$reportParameter = new-object Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("parameter", "value")
$rvwp.OverrideParameters.Add($reportParameter)
```